# Spring property value inside annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

How can I get property value inside an annotation. For example I have an annotation

```
@GetMyValue(value1="Val1",intVal=10)
```

Now I want "Val1" and 10 to be coming from a property file. I tried

```
@GetMyValue(value1="${test.value}",intVal="${test.int.value}")
```

Which doesn't work.

I understand I can use

```
@Value("${test.value}")
String value;

@Value("${test.int.value}")
int intValue;
```

I don't want that, it need to be inside an annotation. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In the Spring @Value the replacement of the placeholder is not done inside the annotation but by the framework when inspecting the bean.

See

- `DefaultListableBeanFactory#doResolveDependency`
- `DefaultListableBeanFactory#resolveEmbeddedValue`
- `org.springframework.util.StringValueResolver`

So, you have to "manually" get the annotation value1 and intVal (which should be a string in your annotation) and resolve them against your properties file.

Answer (score 0):

This need involve more code works I think, but maybe you can have a workaround, for example, not hardcode the value for `@GetMyValue` annonation, just introduce two parameters in a config bean.

```
private String stringVal;
private int intVal;
```

then you can use this two params in you annonation by spEL.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how:

```
GetMyValue(value1="#{'${test.value}'}",intVal="#{'${test.int.value}'}")
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. Thanks